# Can I use both static and dynamic allocation in FreeRTOS?

Tags: allocation, freertos

I have some modules of application designed for static allocation, and some modules designed for dynamic allocation.

Can I use both static and dynamic allocation in one application, like this?

```
#define configSUPPORT_DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION 1
#define configSUPPORT_STATIC_ALLOCATION  1
```

Are there any disadvantages of this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.freertos.org/Static_Vs_Dynamic_Memory_Allocation.html), you can use both in the same application.

> Both methods have pros and cons, and both methods can be used within
> the same RTOS application.